# Any jQuery plugin for generating table of contents for multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are some very nice jQuery plugins for generating table of contents for a single web page, as introduced here:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/5-jquery-table-content-toc-plugins/

However none can generate a TOC for multiple-pages documents. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this on the client-side only, since the javascript can not know what pages are available; In comparision to generating a TOC for a HTML page, where all the necessary information is already available, the javascript would have to follow each any every link on the website and therefore load all the websites content, which somewhat defeats the purpose of a TOC.

You might however be able to do this easily on the server-side using PHP or the like.

Comment: You are right. I am using Python. I suppose I need to use a HTML parser to get the HTML headlines for the TOC. Thanks!

Comment: depending on how well-formed your input HTML is: If it is not, I suggest using "beatiful soup" to parse the HTML, since it can handle all kinds of hickups.

Comment: ... but it might suffice to just ```re.search('<title>([^<]+)', html)``` :)

Comment: Should be more complicated than that, because I still need to get the ID of the headings for generating the right link, right?

Comment: Right. So try beautiful soup. here's the documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ You can basically just search for all h1 tags like this: ```soup.find_all('h1')```